# Hibernate doesn't insert child entities: Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have four classes: `Alien`, `AlienAppartment`, `AlienBuilding` and `AlienBedroom`. They all have a `ManyToOne` relationship:

```
Alien -> has many AlienBuilding -> has many AlienAppartment -> has many AlienBedroom
```

I'm trying to insert a JSON with `AlienBuilding` object via this controller:

**AlienController.java**:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class AliensController {
    @Autowired
    private AlienBuildingRepository alienBuildingRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AlienRepository alienRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AlienBedroomRepository alienBedroomRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AlienAppartmentRepository alienAppartmentRepository;
    
    ...
 
    @GetMapping("/api/aliens/buildings/insert")
    @Transactional
    public String insertBuilding(
                    @RequestBody AlienBuilding alienBuilding)  {
     alienBuildingRepository.save(alienBuilding);

     return "OK";
    }
}
```

**JSON**:

```
{"id":null,"alien":{"id":null,"name":"some alien"},"appartments":[{"id":null,"alienBedrooms":[{"id":null,"description":"cool"}]}]}
```

However all I get is

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
```

output in console. In debugger, however I can see that the JSON has been mapped to the `AlienBuilding` object.

I can try to get it insert some things via

```
    @GetMapping("/api/aliens/buildings/insert")
    @Transactional
    public String insertBuilding(
                    @RequestBody AlienBuilding alienBuilding)  {
        //alienBuildingRepository.save(alienBuilding);

        alienRepository.save(alienBuilding.getAlien());
        for (AlienAppartment appartment: alienBuilding.getAppartments())  {
            for (AlienBedroom bedroom: appartment.getAlienBedrooms())  {
                alienBedroomRepository.save(bedroom);
                alienBedroomRepository.flush();
            }

            alienAppartmentRepository.save(appartment);
            alienAppartmentRepository.flush();
        }

        alienBuildingRepository.save(alienBuilding);
        alienBuildingRepository.flush();

        return "OK";
    }
```

and I would get this output:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into aliens (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into alien_bedrooms (appartment_id, description, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into alien_appartments (building_id, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into alien_buildings (alien_id, id) values (?, ?)
```

But `building_id` column in `alien_appartments` table would be empty as well as the `appartment_id` column in `alien_bedrooms` table

These are my entities:

**Alien.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aliens")
public class Alien  {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    public Alien()  {}

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alien", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<AlienBuilding> buildings;

    /**
     * Getters,setters
     */
```

**AlienAppartment.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alien_appartments")
public class AlienAppartment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )
    public Long id;

    public AlienAppartment() {
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appartment", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AlienBedroom> alienBedrooms;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private AlienBuilding building;


    /**
     * Getters,setters
     */
```

**AlienBedroom.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alien_bedrooms")
public class AlienBedroom {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;

    public AlienBedroom()  {}

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "appartment_id")
    @JsonIgnore
   private AlienAppartment appartment;

    /**
     * Getters,setters
     */
```

**AlienBuilding.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alien_buildings")
public class AlienBuilding {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public AlienBuilding() {
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "alien_id")
    private Alien alien;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "building", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<AlienAppartment> appartments;

    /**
     * Getters, setters
     */
```

**Repositories**:

```
@Repository
public interface AlienAppartmentRepository extends
                JpaRepository<AlienAppartment, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface AlienBedroomRepository extends JpaRepository<AlienBedroom, Long> {
}

@Repository
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public interface AlienBuildingRepository
        extends JpaRepository<AlienBuilding, Long> {
}

@Repository
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public interface AlienRepository extends JpaRepository<Alien, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Please provide hibernate version, dialect and config that you use.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this:

1. I added `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to everything:

```
public class Alien  {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alien", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<AlienBuilding> buildings;
...
}
```

```
public class AlienAppartment  {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "appartment", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AlienBedroom> alienBedrooms;
...
}
```

etc

and

2. I made sure the `Many` side of the `OneToMany` relationship has the reference to the `One` side. It's needed because say, if I insert a building, if the building has a reference to an alien, the alien would be inserted too. Because the alien is the `One` side, it doesn't need to have a reference to its parent `building` object that contains it. The building however needs a reference to the alien - both to trigger the insert and also because the alien's id is **part** of the table associated with the building entity. Similarly because `bedroom` is a `Many` side of the `@OneToMany` connection to the `appartment` (one appartment has many bedrooms, each bedroom has only one appartment), and the appartment_id is part of the `bedrooms` table, a bedroom **must** contain a reference to the appartment:

```
@GetMapping("/api/aliens/buildings/insert")
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager", readOnly=false, propagation =  Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public String insertBuilding(
                    @RequestBody AlienBuilding alienBuilding)  {
        for (AlienAppartment appartment: alienBuilding.getAppartments())  {
            appartment.setBuilding(alienBuilding);

            for (AlienBedroom bedroom: appartment.getAlienBedrooms())  {
                bedroom.setAppartment(appartment);
            }
        }

        alienBuildingRepository.save(alienBuilding);
        alienBuildingRepository.flush();

        return "OK";
    }
```

And the JSON I send:

```
{"id":null,"alien":{"id":null,"name":"awesome alien"},"appartments":[{"id":null,"alienBedrooms":[{"id":null,"description":"awesome bedroom"}]}]}
```

How things look in debugger reference-wise (breakpoint set on the `alienBuildingRepository.save(alienBuilding);` line, right before the insert of the building in the controller):

[image]